# Conditional probability with word play

Tags: conditional-probability

I have been working on this question for a while and I haven't obtained any reasonable results:

> In a city, 70% of the inhabitants are non-smokers. Specialists
>   estimate that there is a 45% chance that smokers will suffer from lung
>   cancer at some point their lives while the probability is 10% for
>   non-smokers. If a person is chosen at random in this city, what is the
>   probability that this person will not develop lung cancer given that
>   this person is a non-smoker?

I know that:

`P(B|A) = P(B ^ A) / P(A)`

Where the symbol `^` indicates `intersection`. To this question, I believe, this formula applies as:

`P(will not dev. lung cancer|non-smoker) = P(no lung cancer ^ non-smoker) / P(non-smoker)`

It is given that P(non-smoker) is `0.7`.

However, obtaining the intersection of `no lung cancer` and `non-smoker` is the problem for me; I create a Venn diagram such that `A` (no-lung cancer) and `B` (non-smoker). Yet, how do I calculate the intersection of the two?

Is there something that I am missing because of the word play in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much of the information in the question is superfluous. All you need to know is that the probability that a non-smoker will develop lung cancer at some point is $0.1$. Thus, the probability that a non-smoker will **not** develop lung cancer at some point is $1-0.1=0.9$, or $90$% if you prefer to express your probabilities as percentages.

The $70$% figure is irrelevant: it doesn’t matter how likely a randomly selected person is to be a non-smoker, because we’re told that in fact a non-smoker was chosen. For the same reason, probabilities involving smokers are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe the same applies for `P(is a smoker and will develop lung cancer)` = 45% and `P(will not develop lung cancer|is smoker)` = 55%, since this information is already present in the info given within the question?

Comment: @arin: Your second probability is right, but the first isn’t: $$\Bbb P(\text{will develop lung cancer}\mid\text{smoker})=0.45\;,$$ but $$\Bbb P(\text{smoker and will develop lung cancer})=0.3\cdot0.45=0.135\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the events be:

- $S$: Choose a smoker at random
- $C|S$: Develop cancer, given is a smoker
- $C|\hat S$: Develop cancer, given is not a smoker

Now, from the problem statement we know:

- $P(S)$= 0.7
- $P(C|S)$=0.45
- $P(C|\hat S)$=0.10

The answer to the question as you stated it is $1-P(C| \hat S) = 1-0.10 = 0.90$

But this does not utilize all the information given in the problem statement, in most textbooks they want to show a typical example of the law of [total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) that may be more illustrative, like obtaining the probability of develping cancer from a person chosen at random. That would be like this:

From total probability law, note that $C$ and $\hat C$ are partitions of the probability space (this is, they are pairwise disjoint subsets of the probability space):

- $P( \hat C)= 1 - P(C) = 1 - (P(C,S) + P(C, \hat S))$

And using the conditional probability definition that you mentioned, we obtain:

- $P(C,S) = P(C|S)*P(S) = 0.45 * 0.7 = 0.315$
- $P(C, \hat S) = P(C| \hat S)*P(\hat S) = 0.10 * 0.3 = 0.03$

Hence:

- $P(\hat C) = 1 - (0.315 + 0.03) = 0.655$